# Json data ingestion in kylo

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

[image]I am facing an issue when i try to ingest json data through data ingest and standard ingest template.
After initialize feed it is going into failure feed. I am able to see hive tables with json attributes created but not the folder structure in hdfs.

Please find the logs and screen shots of kylo attached.enter image description here

```
2017-09-03 08:21:33,205 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] 2017-09-07 00:00:01,724 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Error checking to see if Kylo is available. Please ensure Kylo is up and running.
```

2017-09-07 00:00:01,725 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Kylo is not available to process requests yet.  This task will exit and wait for its next schedule interval.
2017-09-07 00:00:01,725 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Reporting Task Aborted.  Last Event Recorded was: 6269977
2017-09-07 00:00:06,730 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Error checking to see if Kylo is available. Please ensure Kylo is up and running.
2017-09-07 00:00:06,731 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Kylo is not available to process requests yet.  This task will exit and wait for its next schedule interval.
2017-09-07 00:00:06,731 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Reporting Task Aborted.  Last Event Recorded was: 6269977
2017-09-07 00:00:07,004 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@8f5565c checkpointed with 14020 Records and 0 Swap Files in 207 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 2 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 0 millis), max Transaction ID 76071
2017-09-07 00:00:11,735 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Error checking to see if Kylo is available. Please ensure Kylo is up and running.
2017-09-07 00:00:11,736 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Kylo is not available to process requests yet.  This task will exit and wait for its next schedule interval.
2017-09-07 00:00:11,736 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Reporting Task Aborted.  Last Event Recorded was: 6269977
2017-09-07 00:00:16,742 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Error checking to see if Kylo is available. Please ensure Kylo is up and running.
2017-09-07 00:00:16,742 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Kylo is not available to process requests yet.  This task will exit and wait for its next schedule interval.
2017-09-07 00:00:16,742 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Reporting Task Aborted.  Last Event Recorded was: 6269977
2017-09-07 00:00:21,749 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Error checking to see if Kylo is available. Please ensure Kylo is up and running.
2017-09-07 00:00:21,749 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Kylo is not available to process requests yet.  This task will exit and wait for its next schedule interval.
2017-09-07 00:00:21,749 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] c.t.n.p.r.KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask KyloProvenanceEventReportingTask[id=17ff8df2-015d-1000-7741-d474a8a3404d] Reporting Task Aborted.  Last Event Recorded was: 6269977
2017-09-07 00:00:25,600 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] c.t.nifi.v2.init.InitializeFeed InitializeFeed[id=2b1f1ef0-4e16-1bd6-f57d-9191210e2a13] InitializeFeed[id=2b1f1ef0-4e16-1bd6-f57d-9191210e2a13] failed to process due to org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error; rolling back session: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
2017-09-07 00:00:25,602 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] c.t.nifi.v2.init.InitializeFeed
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.metadata.rest.client.MetadataClient.get(MetadataClient.java:700) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.metadata.rest.client.MetadataClient.get(MetadataClient.java:692) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.metadata.rest.client.MetadataClient.lambda$getCurrentInitStatus$1(MetadataClient.java:263) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.metadata.rest.client.MetadataClient.nullable(MetadataClient.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.metadata.rest.client.MetadataClient.getCurrentInitStatus(MetadataClient.java:263) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.nifi.v2.core.metadata.MetadataClientRecorder.getInitializationStatus(MetadataClientRecorder.java:217) ~[na:na]
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.nifi.v2.init.InitializeFeed.onTrigger(InitializeFeed.java:116) ~[kylo-nifi-core-processors-0.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) ~[nifi-api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1064) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]

Comment: It looks like your log file was truncated. Could you run the feed again and update this post? Also, please look to see if there are any lines that say ERROR or WARN in the log file.

Comment: I have added the updated logs.. I am able to see errors in kylo metadata service.
Rest client url is as follows in kylo metadata service
http://localhost:8400/proxy/v1/metadata

Comment: It looks like the InitializeFeed processor is receiving a 500 Internal Server Error from Kylo. Could you look for a corresponding error in the /var/log/kylo-services/kylo-services.log file?